# Having trouble extracting img src from multiple URLs with beautifulsoup4 on Python3

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a scraper that will go through a list of product page URLs, parse the data and extract the img src URLs from the photo reel, which are under 'li' elements, which is under a 'ul' element with the unique class 'bxslider'. I would simply soup.findAll('img'['src']) but there are many other src imgs on the site, which I don't need. I also need to exclude any 'li' tags with the class 'bx-clone'.
I am using selenium, beautifulsoup and pandas.

The HTML I need to scrape:

```
<ul class="bxslider" style="width: 1315%; position: relative; left: -410px;"><li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;" class="bx-clone"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/b5/48/b548ce05-1ee1-486b-9f33-ea61625d25ba.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/50/1f/501f8112-f6a7-4710-bd48-3acb0976e8f3.jpg?timestamp=1600972726783"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/55/bb/55bb9511-676b-4585-8cf2-99af9ba8baca.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/06/a7/06a700dd-8350-4932-88e9-c941e73e0def.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/8c/92/8c92207d-c422-4d94-894c-911a5330e227.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/e0/22/e0224832-75f5-432a-a223-177ff7ffd03c.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/8a/e1/8ae1e8d4-76a1-4161-9b17-b7a97e1779fc.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/fc/d5/fcd5a35b-8fb5-463e-9a47-804850f17825.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/98/2e/982ea3c5-ce28-49c8-bef5-b0f85bd99807.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/23/e1/23e153df-75af-4f1b-a4dd-3e0fb1e5a28f.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/94/02/940268f9-04ed-4650-bd9f-01b113b5059b.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/b5/48/b548ce05-1ee1-486b-9f33-ea61625d25ba.jpg"></li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;" class="bx-clone"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/50/1f/501f8112-f6a7-4710-bd48-3acb0976e8f3.jpg?timestamp=1600972726783"></li></ul>
```

The code I've written to scrape the img srcs and append to a the imgs table

```
from testurls import tdurls as urllist

# make an empty list to scrape into
imgs = []  
print('debug mode')

for url in urllist:
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    print('Url loop set up, moving deeper...')
    soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
    bxslider = soup.find('ul', {'class':'bxslider'})
    for li in bxslider:
        print('Printing bxslider...')
        print(bxslider)
        try:
            bxs = bxslider.findChildren('li')
            print('Printing li children...')
            print(li)
            for li in bxs:
                h = li.findAll('img'['src'])
                imgs.append(h)
                print('Found children...')
                print(h)
                
                        
        
        except:        
            bxslider.findChildren("li", { "class" : "bx-clone" })




print('Alright... how did we do?')
print(imgs)                            
imgdf = pd.DataFrame({'imgs':imgs})
ndf = imgdf.append(urllist, ignore_index=True)
print(ndf)
ndf.to_csv('C:/Users/niall/.spyder-py3/didthisworklol.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

I am quite lost, and am fairly new to python and all of the modules currently in use. I need those image links to be in one cell, alongside the corresponding product page URL, so that the rows would look like this with only a comma as a delimiter:
`productpagelink, image link | image link | image link`

I included the pandas bit at the end, because while it looked like my imgs list was being correctly appended, I don't want to leave room for more error on my part than I should, and figured there might be an obvious tweak there.
If I am missing anything you need to help, let me know and I will make an edit. Thank you!

EDITS: I cannot share the URL as it is behind a password protected website; Selenium loads up just fine and goes through each URL, though.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: why don't you call boxslider.findAll('img'['src'])?

Comment: @AndrejKesely - updated post, but the pages I'm scraping are behind a password protected site.

Comment: What is the product page?  Just the main url snippet? e.g. - `//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/b5/48`

Comment: @D-E-N while this did save me some lines of code (thank you!), it hasn't solved my problem. Gonna keep trying to debug, I think my new code's problem lies in finding the bxslider class ul tag.. printing that variable out basically gave me all of the HTML that comes after it in the document. Hmm..

Comment: @MarkMoretto yes - that's really all I need to extract :)

Comment: Okay.  I posted something, but you don't need anything besides standard libraries.  And, python 3.5+.

Answer (score 0):

Probably unpopular method, but there's always the `re` module.  It's a lot more work, but a lot more fun, too.

```
import re

html = """
<ul class="bxslider" style="width: 1315%; position: relative; left: -410px;"><li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;" class="bx-clone"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/b5/48/b548ce05-1ee1-486b-9f33-ea61625d25ba.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/50/1f/501f8112-f6a7-4710-bd48-3acb0976e8f3.jpg?timestamp=1600972726783"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/55/bb/55bb9511-676b-4585-8cf2-99af9ba8baca.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/06/a7/06a700dd-8350-4932-88e9-c941e73e0def.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/8c/92/8c92207d-c422-4d94-894c-911a5330e227.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/e0/22/e0224832-75f5-432a-a223-177ff7ffd03c.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/8a/e1/8ae1e8d4-76a1-4161-9b17-b7a97e1779fc.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/fc/d5/fcd5a35b-8fb5-463e-9a47-804850f17825.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/98/2e/982ea3c5-ce28-49c8-bef5-b0f85bd99807.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/23/e1/23e153df-75af-4f1b-a4dd-3e0fb1e5a28f.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/94/02/940268f9-04ed-4650-bd9f-01b113b5059b.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/b5/48/b548ce05-1ee1-486b-9f33-ea61625d25ba.jpg"></li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;" class="bx-clone"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/50/1f/501f8112-f6a7-4710-bd48-3acb0976e8f3.jpg?timestamp=1600972726783"></li></ul>
"""

# Retrieve only list elements based on given <ul> class
list_section_pattern = r'(?:<ul class="bxslider" .*?>)(?P<target>.*?)(?:</ul>)'
p = re.compile(list_section_pattern, flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
list_section = p.search(html).group("target")



# Match pattern to get all URLs; This is pretty straightforward.
href_pattern = r'<img src="(.*?)">'
p = re.compile(href_pattern)

# This should be a list of parsed URLs
urls = p.findall(list_section)


def get_root_url(url_path):
    """Split by forward-slash; Keep everything except image filename."""
    return "/".join(url_path.split(r"/")[:-1])


# Create a dictionary of url roots and image url lists.
url_dict = {}
for url in urls:
    root = get_root_url(url)
    if not root in url_dict:
        url_dict[root] = [url]
    else:
        url_dict[root].append(url)

# Output string for csv file
csv_string = ""
for k, v in url_dict.items():
    # .join() elements with vertical bar.
    tmp = " | ".join(v)
    csv_string += f"{k}, {tmp}\n" # Add a newline character

with open(r"C:\Users\niall\.spyder-py3\didthisworklol.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as csvf:
    csvf.write(csv_string)
```

Result (in Excel):

[image]

EDIT: Here's some BeautifulSoup action:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# This should return all unordered list sections with the class 'bxslider'
for chunk in soup.find_all("ul", class_="bxslider"):

    # List comprehension to get all the urls from the img tag.
    urls = [img.attrs["src"] for img in chunk.find_all("img")]
```

Then you can use the same method as above to send to a file.

Comment: Ah, this looked good - I shoved it all into a for loop, that would grab the product html for each page and run your code on loop, set the html variable as the page's source, but I am getting an attribute error with `list_section = p.search(html).group("target")`
Error is:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: That probably means you didn't find anything.  It probably meant that the class tag wasn't in the right spot, but you could do something like `r'(?:<ul .*?class="bxslider" .*?>)(?P<target>.*?)(?:</ul>)'`, which just adds another wildcard before the 'class' attribute.

Comment: @haise0 In any case, I added a section for BeautifulSoup if you want to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
html = """
<ul class="bxslider" style="width: 1315%; position: relative; left: -410px;"><li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;" class="bx-clone"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/b5/48/b548ce05-1ee1-486b-9f33-ea61625d25ba.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/50/1f/501f8112-f6a7-4710-bd48-3acb0976e8f3.jpg?timestamp=1600972726783"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/55/bb/55bb9511-676b-4585-8cf2-99af9ba8baca.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/06/a7/06a700dd-8350-4932-88e9-c941e73e0def.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/8c/92/8c92207d-c422-4d94-894c-911a5330e227.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/e0/22/e0224832-75f5-432a-a223-177ff7ffd03c.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/8a/e1/8ae1e8d4-76a1-4161-9b17-b7a97e1779fc.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/fc/d5/fcd5a35b-8fb5-463e-9a47-804850f17825.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/98/2e/982ea3c5-ce28-49c8-bef5-b0f85bd99807.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/23/e1/23e153df-75af-4f1b-a4dd-3e0fb1e5a28f.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/94/02/940268f9-04ed-4650-bd9f-01b113b5059b.jpg"></li>
       <li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/b5/48/b548ce05-1ee1-486b-9f33-ea61625d25ba.jpg"></li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 410px;" class="bx-clone"><img src="//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/50/1f/501f8112-f6a7-4710-bd48-3acb0976e8f3.jpg?timestamp=1600972726783"></li></ul>
"""
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
images = doc.select('ul.bxslider').selects('img').src
rows = [[src] for src in images] # Change [] to [[]]
utils.save2csv('didthisworklol.csv',rows,newline='') # Save data to file
```

Result:

```
//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/b5/48/b548ce05-1ee1-486b-9f33-ea61625d25ba.jpg
//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/50/1f/501f8112-f6a7-4710-bd48-3acb0976e8f3.jpg?timestamp=1600972726783
//d1w0x2adoh4nzy.cloudfront.net/55/bb/55bb9511-676b-4585-8cf2-99af9ba8baca.jpg
......
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples